# Setting SVG element width/height attributes using CSS in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I'm trying to set the width and height attributes of SVG elements using CSS instead of putting them inline but I can't seem to get it working in firefox.

When I set the width/height inline on the element it displays with no problems.

```
 <rect x="10px" y="50px" fill="green" width="20px" height="20px" />
```

When I try to set the width/height using CSS it works in Chrome but not in Firefox.

```
.box {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

<rect class="box" x="50px" y="50px" fill="green" />
```

- Tried this in both firefox 43 and 36 with the same behavior.
- When I inspect the missing SVG elements in firefox it looks like the CSS is being applied and the computed styles show the correct width/height values.
- I'm hoping I'm just doing something silly and Chrome is just "making it work".  I'd like to avoid browser specific CSS if at all possible.

[JSFiddle examples](https://jsfiddle.net/DForshner/t9weLsod/)

Comment: Could you simplify the example in jsfiddle?

Comment: Seems I did it myself: https://jsfiddle.net/fpqs09a0/

Comment: Only chrome supports setting of width and height of rectangle from css. IE, FF and Opera 12 don't.

Comment: @Qwertiy - That would explain what I'm seeing.  Do you know of a link that talks about that?  My google-fu appears to be lacking today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not all SVG element attributes can be styled with CSS.  Only the ones designated as "properties" can be.  See the list below from the SVG specification.

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html

The (in development) SVG 2 specification will allow all attributes to be styled with CSS.  And some browsers are starting to support that.  But for now you won't be able to do it.

**Update:** Not all attributes will be styleable in SVG2. The list of [styleable presentation attributes is here](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#attindex-PresentationAttributes).

Comment: Thanks.  Now that I know what to look for I found an [article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/11/styling-and-animating-svgs-with-css/#styling-svgs-with-css) that expands on your answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I've always wrapped my SVG's within a `<span>` or `<div>` and then sized up that element versus the SVG itself.

```
div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-30deg);
// you can essentially do everything in the div versus the svg
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  fill: white
}
```

Comment: I think I worded my question poorly.  I'm looking to set the width & height of elements like rect/foreignObject/etc. using CSS not the parent <svg> element.

Comment: See jsfiddle link in my comment to the question.